# Does apt-update ever require confirmation?

Tags: docker, apt

I've seen `apt-get update -y` in some Dockerfiles. Is there an edge-case where `apt-get update` would require confirmation? I'm hesitant to supply it in my Dockerfile without knowing under what conditions it could become relevant.

If I do not supply it, is there any situation where the update would not execute and break my Docker build?

Answer (score -1):

By "confirmation", do you just mean asking for yes or no? There are several packages that I have installed where apt reads a download list of some kind and lists the downloads, then then asks the user Y/n if they want to download all of the listed packages. It's not even an edge case, its fairly common, and yes `-y` would prevent apt from needing the confirmation.

Comment: I'm asking about `apt-get update`, not `apt-get upgrade`